# AFNetworking Post request not working

Tags: ios, .net, web-services, afnetworking

I am facing a problem in making a POST request to a .net webservice method.
I have made a lot of post request but i just don't seem to get the problem i am facing here
The request is made successfully with the help of Rest client
But it always gives me a 400 error
 I am using AFNetworking to make the post request
Please find the code below if something is wrong

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://WebService.svc"]; 
NSMutableDictionary *params=[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[params setValue:@"cabbage123" forKey:@""];

AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
[httpClient setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];
[httpClient setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];

[httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];

[httpClient postPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Users/%@",userId] parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    // Print the response body in text
    NSLog(@"Response: %@",responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

}];
```

And i get a html response with this error

```
AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLRequestErrorKey=<NSMutableURLRequest http://WebService.svc/Users/userid>, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://WebService.svc/Users/userid, NSLocalizedDescription=Expected status code in (200-299), got 400, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7ba6df0>}
```

Comment: Have you tried tracking this call with "charles". Make sure that the call which you are sending from rest client and AFNetworking are same, you might be missing some headers

Comment: I think there is problem in the way i am sending the parameters

Comment: you can share the solution here too, so that next time if someone gets stuck in similar situation he will be having a solution ready for him.

Comment: I am still searching for the solution.Will upload once done

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some problem with AfNetworking for WCF web-services.
Ultimately i could connect and use the web-service by using the standard NSURLConnection class. Though i am facing the same problem for PUT request now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to setup AFNetworking to allow invalid certificates?

```
httpClient.allowsInvalidSSLCertificate = YES;
```

of if you want to use operations.

```
AFSecurityPolicy *sec=[[AFSecurityPolicy alloc] init];
[sec setAllowInvalidCertificates:YES];
operation.securityPolicy=sec;
```